# Is there "event prevent default" equivalent in Android?

Tags: javascript, android, events

I need to know if radio button is checked while i click it. Unfortunately click is changing his state to checked. I want to know if android has some equivalent of javascripts event prevent default.

Comment: Could you paste some code? Also, RadioButtons are generally used within RadioGroups and they have callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there a direct way to get this, but this can be done using the following way:-

```
radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        if (b) {
                 //checked
               // RadioButton  bt = (RadioButton) compoundButton;
              //  bt.setChecked(false);

           }else{ 
                // not checked
         }
    }
});
```

or else you can use `radioButton.isChecked()` to detect if it is checked or not and  radioButton.setChecked(false) to uncheck it;.